# Splunk need help in extracting ERROR messages from logs

Tags: regex, splunk

Can someone pls help in extracting all the logs with "level": ERROR and extract the message into another field .For eg. message : Example1.Example2: Example3: 2 need to extracted to fied.TravellllgPeeele_INR

The log looks like this :

```
| "level":"ERROR","loggerName":"Log1.Log2LLogLog3","message":"Example1.Example2: Example3: 2 need to extracted to fied.TravellllgPeeele_INR","endOfBatch":false
```

I am able to extract all ERROR with the below rex, however unable to extract message.

```
| rex "(?<Err>ERROR)" 
| search Err=*
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got the first extraction correct, just do another like it:

```
| rex field=_raw "message[[:punct:]]+(?<message>[^\"]+)"
```

This will grab everything after "`message":"`" until it hits another quote mark

#### added per comment request

If you only want to extract `message` if "ERROR" is present in the event, the regex is similarly simple:

```
| rex field=_raw "ERROR.+?message[[:punct:]]+(?<message>[^\"]+)"
```

##### edit

If you can have any punctuation *leading* the message, just match the `":"` by using `[[:punct:]]{3}`:

```
| rex field=_raw "ERROR.+?message[[:punct:]]{3}(?<message>[^\"]+)"
```

Comment: thank you it works to extract the message, I used comma instead of " like this rex "(?<Err>ERROR)" |rex field=_raw "message[[:punct:]]+(?<Dmsg>[^\,]+)".But can you also please help in extracting only the records with Dmsg field where ERROR keyword is present in the logs

Comment: @Diksha - see edit

Comment: the above rex works perfectly, except when it encounters '*' in the message: Eg:"message":"***************************","endOfBatch":false,.In this case , it extracts endOfBatch\":false as the message , whereas it should extract whatever is inside the double quotes and comma, in this case ******. Can you please help?

Comment: @Diksha - see edit